# Solving the Lotka-McKendrick model with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations, ecology

The Lotka-McKendrick model is a demographic model that represents the way a population changes over time due to fertility and mortality. For an age-specific population density $ u(a, t) $, and a total birth rate $ \Lambda(t) $, the following equations should be satisfied:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & = & -\mu(a) u(a, t) \\
\Lambda(t) & = & u(0, t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} da\,u(a,t) f(a,t) \\
u(a, 0) & = & u_0(a)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Here, $ \mu(a) $ is an age-specific [force of mortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_of_mortality), $ f(a) $ is an age-specific fertility rate, and $ u_0(a) $ is an initial condition.

If it weren't for the integral in the boundary condition $ \Lambda(T) = u(0, t) $, we'd be home free. In fact, `DSolve` would suffice, using the standard technique of integrating along the characteristic lines of the first-order PDE:

```
lkPDE = {D[u[a, t], a] + D[u[a, t], t] == -\[Mu][a]*u[a, t], 
  u[a, 0] == u0[a]};

DSolve[lkPDE, u[a, t], {a, t}]
(* {{u[a, t] -> 
     E^(Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a}] - Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], 
       {K[1], 1, a - t}])*u0[a - t]}} *)
```

Sticking the integral in there makes everything fall apart.

```
lkIntegral =
 u[0, t] == Integrate[u[x, t]*f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}];

DSolve[Flatten@{lkPDE, lkIntegral}, u[a, t], {a, t}]
(* returns unevaluated *)
```

You can write an analytic solution down, but as an alternative, I would like to use `NDSolve`, especially as numerical methods will generalize to cases where the analytic solutions don't exist or are too complicated to be useful.

Sadly, `NDSolve` also chokes, even with appropriate concessions to reality. Let's choose very simple parameters:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(a) & = & 1/80 \\
f(a) & = & \left\{ \begin{array} 
 & 1/10 & 20 \le a < 45 \\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. 
\end{eqnarray}$$

Even so, we need a simpler integral condition because `Integrate` isn't quite smart to handle that piecewise function.

```
simpleLkIntegral =
 u[0, t] == Integrate[u[x, t], {x, 20, 45}]/10

NDSolve[{
  lkPDE /. \[Mu][_] -> 1/80 /. u0[a_] :> 1/80,
  simpleLkIntegral
  },
 u,
 {a, 0, 100},
 {t, 0, 100}]
(* returns unevaluated, with the an NDSolve::litarg message complaining about the integral *)
```

In order to appease `NDSolve::litarg`, I try rewriting the integral with `a` replacing `x` as the variable of integration, which yields no joy:

```
simpleLkIntegral2 =
 u[0, t] == Integrate[u[a, t], {a, 20, 45}]/10

NDSolve[{
  lkPDE /. \[Mu][_] -> 1/80 /. u0[a_] :> 1/80,
  simpleLkIntegral2
  },
 u,
 {a, 0, 100},
 {t, 0, 100}]
(* returns unevaluated, with a
  NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {u[a,t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.
 *)
```

At this point, I feel like I've more or less run out of road, but was wondering if there was some way to force `NDSolve` to do what I want.
**UPDATE**: I did try the model again with a different set of initial conditions, ones which allow for consistency between the boundary and initial conditions from $ t = 0 $ on, as shown below:

```
simpleLkInit = With[{m = 1/80},
   u0[a_] :> Piecewise[{{c - m*a, 0 <= a <= c/m}}, 0]];

simpleLkNormalization = First@Solve[
   {simpleLkIntegral2 /. t -> 0 /. u[a_, 0] :> u0[a] /. simpleLkInit, 
    c > 0}, c]
(* c -> 65/96 *)
```

Plugging this into `NDSolve` gives the same issue with overdetermination (so presumably the consistency of the boundary condition is never even checked):

```
NDSolve[{lkPDE /. \[Mu][_] -> 1/80 /. simpleLkInit /. 
   simpleLkNormalization, simpleLkIntegral2}, u, {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 
  100}]
(* Unevaluated, with NDSolve::overdet message *)
```

While the strategy of discretizing the system in age manually, as in
[Chris K's fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230405/531), is entirely viable, this essentially boils down to using the method of lines, which is the approach `NDSolve` itself uses. I would like to see if `NDSolve` itself can do the discretization, or at least if I can use it to drive move of the problem.

Comment: We can solve it, but with message: `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`

Comment: So, the solution is supposed to be unsmooth somewhere? (The initial condition is enough to determine the classic solution. )

Comment: @xzczd It is not only an unsmooth solution  but not unique as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The question still needs clarification in my view. Since we're not looking for a classic solution, additional condition is needed to determine a particular solution, then what's it?  I guess it's certain continuity or conservation. (Just like the [heat continuity condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120812/1871) for heat conduction equation. ) But I can't go further given that I'm not familiar with the underlying model.

Comment: @xzczd  It is also known as the [von Foerster equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Foerster_equation).  It's a standard model in mathematical demography.  It includes three processes: aging ($\partial u/\partial a$), death ($-\mu(a)u$), and reproduction ($\int f(a)u(a) da$).  Despite the weird boundary condition, it is linear.  You can read more about it [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/3/23/files/2019/06/pop.pdf).

Comment: @ChrisK Wait, since $a$ is age, we always have $a\geq 0$, and $u$ for $a<0$ is actually undefined, right?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, $u(a)$ only makes sense for $a \geq 0$.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not an expert on age-structured populations (particularly this continuous-time model) and I know [better numerical methods](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.m.deroos/PSPManalysis/index.html) exist, but why not just discretize in age `a` and solve the resulting large system of ODEs?

(**NB:** doublecheck the details of my discretization if you use this for anything serious; I wasn't too careful in how I put the `da`'s in!)

```
imax = 100;
da = 1.0;

f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/10, 0];
μ[a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := If[a <= 10, 1/80, 0];

eqns = Join[
   {u[0]'[t] == -μ[0] u[0][t] - u[0][t]/da + Sum[u[i][t] f[i da], {i, 0, imax}]},
   Table[u[i]'[t] == -(u[i][t] - u[i - 1][t])/da - μ[i da] u[i][t], {i, 1, imax}]
];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[i da], {i, 0, imax}];
unks = Table[u[i], {i, 0, imax}];

tmax = 160;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

frames = Table[
  ListPlot[Table[{i da, u[i][t]}, {i, 0, imax}] /. sol, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 0.06}, PlotLabel -> t, AxesLabel -> {"a", "u"}]
, {t, 0, tmax}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

I started with a step-function of `u0[a]` to illustrate a few things:

1. You can see the population distribution move to the right as individuals age.
2. There's a baby boom when the initial population goes through reproductive ages 20-45, and also echoes as their kids reproduce.
3. The population approaches a stable age distribution, then grows exponentially.
4. Somewhat problematic: the discretization of the advection term results in numerical diffusion, blurring the initial step-function distribution over time.  Higher resolution (smaller `da`) helps, and if you're only interested in the long-term behavior or smooth age-distributions, I think this isn't too bad.  This is where more sophisticated numerical methods may help.

Finally, an advantage of this approach is you can look at the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to get more info.  Linearizing to make a matrix `A`:

```
A = D[eqns /. ((_ == rhs_) -> rhs) /. (var_[t] -> var), {unks}];
{λ, v} = Eigensystem[A];
λ[[-3 ;; -1]]

(* {-0.0370978 + 0.184096 I, -0.0370978 - 0.184096 I, 0.0163063 + 0. I} *)
```

The last eigenvalue is the dominant, which gives the asymptotic growth rate to be 0.0163063 per year.  The subdominant eigenvalues are complex; I think the imaginary part gives the approximate period of those baby boom echoes:

```
Abs[2 π/Im[λ[[-2]]]]
(* 34.1299 *)
```

Finally, the eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue gives the stable age distribution:

```
ListPlot[Abs[v[[-1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT:**

Better yet, you can just convert this to a discrete-time, discrete-state [Leslie matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_matrix) model.  As long as the time step matches the size of the age classes, there is no spurious numerical diffusion.

Make the Leslie matrix:

```
L = SparseArray[
  Join[
    Table[{1, i + 1} -> f[i da] da, {i, 0, imax}],
    Table[{i + 2, i + 1} -> 1 - μ[i da] da, {i, 0, imax - 1}]
  ], {imax + 1, imax + 1}
];
```

Project forward in time:

```
n = Table[If[i <= 11, 1/80, 0], {i, imax + 1}];
res = Join[{n}, Table[n = L.n, {t, 1, tmax}]];

frames = Table[
  ListPlot[res[[t + 1]], PlotLabel -> t da, PlotRange -> {0, da 0.06}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "u"}]
, {t, 0, tmax/da}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Asymptotic growth rate checks out:

```
Log[Max[Re[Eigenvalues[A]]]]/da
(* 0.0162194 *)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I think you'll end up stuck with manual discretization in age, because the boundary condition is so weird compared to most typical PDEs.  The discrete time-step in my matrix approach avoids numerical diffusion, which is important to maintain the shape if there are steps in the initial conditions (this should be a stringent test for any answer that tries to solve this problem).

The only thing I have left to offer is to force `NDSolve` to solve the continuous-time system in the same way as the discrete-time version using `Method->"ExplicitEuler"` and step size equal to the width of an age class.  (note I had to tweak my discretization a little bit).

Here's a nice hi-resolution example:

```
imax = 1000;
da = 0.1;

f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/10, 0];
μ[a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := If[a < 5, 0.1, 0];

eqns = Join[
   {u[0]'[t] == -μ[0] u[0][t] - u[0][t]/da + Sum[u[i][t] f[i da], {i, 0, imax}]},
   Table[u[i]'[t] == -(u[i][t] - u[i - 1][t])/da - μ[(i - 1) da] u[i - 1][t], {i, 1, imax}]
];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[i da], {i, 0, imax}];
unks = Table[u[i], {i, 0, imax}];

tmax = 160;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax},
  Method -> "ExplicitEuler", StartingStepSize -> da][[1]];

frames = Table[
   ListPlot[Table[{i da, u[i][t]}, {i, 0, imax}] /. sol, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}, PlotLabel -> t, AxesLabel -> {"a", "u"}, 
    Joined -> True]
, {t, 0, tmax}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice attempt (+1)! Your solution corresponds to my first solution with the message `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Is that warning really something to worry about? I mean, the dynamics of the system seems to take care of it naturally.

Comment: Yes, it looks natural, but `NDSolve` does not agree with this. :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev In any case, I don't get that error with my code!

Comment: You don't get error since you solved system of ODEs, not PDE.

Answer (score 7):

There is no unique solution for data provided by @Pillsy, since boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. To show it we just use exact solution in a form:

```
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80; u0[a_] := 1/80; 
u[a_, t_] := 
 E^(Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a}] - 
     Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a - t}])*u0[a - t]
u[0, t_] := Integrate[u[x, t], {x, 20, 45}]/25;
```

Now we can plot `u[0,t]` as follows:

```
Plot[u[0, t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
So it is smooth function and we can make interpolation in a form

```
lst = Table[{t, u[0, t] // N}, {t, 0, 100, 1}];

ut = Interpolation[lst];
```

With `ut` we can use `NDSolve` directly

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[a, t], a] + D[v[a, t], t] == -\[Mu][a]*
     v[a, t], v[a, 0] == u0[a], v[0, t] == ut[t]}, 
  v, {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Here we got message `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` Nevertheless numerical solution can be plot and it looks like waved function

```
Plot3D[sol[a, t], {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]
To avoid the inconsistent of boundary and initial conditions we put in the beginning of the code

```
u[0, t_] := Integrate[u[x, t], {x, 20, 45}]/25;
```

Then we get smooth numerical solution
[image: Figure 3]

Now we can use method of line implemented by Chris K with some appropriate modifications

```
Clear[u];

imax = 200;
da = 1/2;

f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/25, 0];
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := 1/80;

eqns = Join[{u[0]'[t] == 
     da/2 Sum[(u[i + 1]'[t] f[(i + 1) da] + u[i]'[t] f[i da]), {i, 0, 
        imax - 1}]}, 
   Table[u[i]'[
      t] == -(u[i][t] - u[i - 1][t])/da - \[Mu][i da] u[i][t], {i, 1, 
     imax}]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[i da], {i, 0, imax}];
unks = Table[u[i], {i, 0, imax}];

tmax = 100;
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
```

We make visualization of numerical solution of the system of ODEs and see identical picture as we got for PDE

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{i da, t, Evaluate[u[i][t] /. sol1]}, {i, 0, imax}, {t,
     0, tmax, 1}], 1], AxesLabel -> {"a", "t", "u"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Figure 4]
And more detailed comparison also shows agreement of two solutions

```
Show[Plot[{sol[10, t]}, {t, 0, 100}], 
 ListPlot[Table[{t, u[20][t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, 100, 2}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 5]

One example of growing population with consistent boundary and initial conditions:

```
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80; u0[a_] := Exp[-a/45]; 
f[a_] := Piecewise[{{1/10/1.2298542626633067, 20 <= x < 45}, {0, 
    True}}]; 
ue[a_, t_] := 
 E^(Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a}] - 
     Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a - t}])*u0[a - t]
u1[t_] := NIntegrate[ue[x, t] f[x], {x, 0, 100}] // Quiet;


lst = Table[{t, u1[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 1}];

ut = Interpolation[lst];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[a, t], a] + D[v[a, t], t] == -\[Mu][a]*
     v[a, t], v[a, 0] == u0[a], v[0, t] == ut[t]}, 
  v, {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Visualisation

```
Plot3D[sol[a, t], {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 6]

And same solution with method of lines:

```
imax = 500;
da = 100/imax;

f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/10/1.2298542626633067, 0];
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := Exp[-a/45];

eqns = Join[{u[0]'[t] == 
     da/2 Sum[(u[i + 1]'[t] f[(i + 1) da] + u[i]'[t] f[i da]), {i, 0, 
        imax - 1}]}, 
   Table[u[i]'[
      t] == -(u[i][t] - u[i - 1][t])/da - \[Mu][i da] u[i][t], {i, 1, 
     imax}]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[i da], {i, 0, imax}];
unks = Table[u[i], {i, 0, imax}];

tmax = 100;
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
```

Let compare two solution and find out that they have small discrepancies (due to large `da`)

```
Table[Show[
  Plot[{sol[i da, t]}, {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"a = ", i da}]], 
  ListPlot[Table[{t, u[i][t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, 100, 2}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red]], {i, 0, imax, 20}]
```

[image: Figure 7]

Last example provided by Pillsy shows divergence of two solutions found out with two methods even if initial data and boundary conditions are consistent. First method:

```
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80; u0[a_] := If[0 <= a <= 325/6, 65/96 - a/80, 0]; 
f[a_] := Piecewise[{{1/10, 20 <= x < 45}, {0, True}}]; 
ue[a_, t_] := 
 E^(Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a}] - 
     Inactive[Integrate][-\[Mu][K[1]], {K[1], 1, a - t}])*u0[a - t]
u1[t_] := NIntegrate[ue[x, t], {x, 20, 45}]/10 // Quiet;

lst = Table[{t, u1[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 1/4}];

ut = Interpolation[lst];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[a, t], a] + D[v[a, t], t] == -\[Mu][a]*
      v[a, t], v[a, 0] == u0[a], v[0, t] == ut[t]}, 
   v, {a, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 100}];
```

Second method:

```
imax = 500;
da = 100/imax;

f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/10, 0];
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := If[0 <= a <= 325/6, 65/96 - a/80, 0];

eqns = Join[{u[0]'[t] == 
     da/2 Sum[(u[i + 1]'[t] f[(i + 1) da] + u[i]'[t] f[i da]), {i, 0, 
        imax - 1}]}, 
   Table[u[i]'[
      t] == -(u[i][t] - u[i - 1][t])/da - \[Mu][i da] u[i][t], {i, 1, 
     imax}]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[i da], {i, 0, imax}];
unks = Table[u[i], {i, 0, imax}];

tmax = 100;
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, unks, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}][[1]];
```

Now we plot solutions together and see divergence

```
Table[Show[ 

Plot[{sol[i da, t]}, {t, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"a = ", i da}]], 
  ListPlot[Table[{t, u[i][t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, 100, 2}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]], {i, 0, imax, 20}]
```

[image: Figure 8]

Nevertheless, we can consider all tests above as verification of numerical method of lines for this problem. Now we make next step to develop code with known error of $h^4$, where $h$ is step size. For this we use function `GaussianQuadratureWeights[]` to integrate with n-point Gaussian formula for quadrature, and function `FiniteDifferenceDerivative` for approximation of derivative $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$ with `DifferenceOrder` of 4. First we call utilities:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]
```

Second step, we define derivative matrix `m` and integral vector `int`:

```
np = 400; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 100];
ugrid = g[[All, 1]]; weights = g[[All, 2]];
fd = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ugrid]; m = 
 fd["DifferentiationMatrix"]; vart = 
 Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; vart1 = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; ux = m.vart; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, Length[ugrid]}];
f[a_] := If[20 <= a < 45, 1/10, 0]; int = 
 Table[f[ugrid[[i]]] weights[[i]], {i, np}];
\[Mu][a_] := 1/80;
u0[a_] := If[0 <= a <= 325/6, 65/96 - a/80, 0];
```

Third step, we define the system of equations:

```
eqns = Join[{D[u[1][t], t] == int.vart1}, 
   Table[D[u[i][t], t] == -ux[[i]] - \[Mu][ugrid[[i]]] u[i][t], {i, 2,
      Length[ugrid]}]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[ugrid[[i]]], {i, Length[ugrid]}];
```

Finally we solve system as

```
tmax = 100;
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

With this code we made research to check how solution diverges with `np` increasing:

```
{np, {u[1][100] /. sol1[[1]], u[np][100] /. sol1[[1]]}}

{100, {4.0455, 0.197089}}

{200, {3.791317314610565`, 0.19572819660924937`}};

{400, {3.6951293716506926`, 0.1949809561721866`}};

{800, {3.70082201902361`, 0.19456320959442788`}};
```

So numerical solution converges very fast with `np` increasing, and for `np=800` we have picture

```
lst1 = Flatten[
   Table[{t, ugrid[[i]], u[i][t] /. sol1[[1]]}, {t, 0, 100, 2}, {i, 1,
      Length[ugrid], 5}], 1];
ListPlot3D[lst1, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "a"}]
```

[image: Figure 9]
We have run several tests with known exact solution and got a good agreement of the exact and numerical solution getting with the last code. Example 1 from [Numerical methods for the Lotka–McKendrick’s equation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82725634.pdf) (there are typos in this paper in equations (6.8),(6,9) I have corrected using Mathematica 12.1):

```
f[a_]:=2; \[Mu][a_] := 1/(1 - a); 
p0[x_] := If[x <= 1/2, (1 - 2 x)^3 (1 - x), 31 (2 x - 1)^3 (1 - x)];
u0[a_] := p0[a];
```

With this data we have to compute `u[a,t]` on `{a,0,1},{t,0,1}` and then compare  exact solution $u(0,t)=B(t)$ with numerical solution:

```
B[t_] := If[t <= 1/2, 
   217 - 186 t - 372 t^2 - 248 t^3 - 216 E^t Cos[t] + 396 E^t Sin[t], 
   1/(Sqrt[E] (Cos[1/2]^2 + Sin[1/2]^2)) (-7 Sqrt[E] Cos[1/2]^2 + 
      6 Sqrt[E] t Cos[1/2]^2 + 12 Sqrt[E] t^2 Cos[1/2]^2 + 
      8 Sqrt[E] t^3 Cos[1/2]^2 - 216 E^(1/2 + t) Cos[1/2]^2 Cos[t] + 
      768 E^t Cos[t] Sin[1/2] - 7 Sqrt[E] Sin[1/2]^2 + 
      6 Sqrt[E] t Sin[1/2]^2 + 12 Sqrt[E] t^2 Sin[1/2]^2 + 
      8 Sqrt[E] t^3 Sin[1/2]^2 - 216 E^(1/2 + t) Cos[t] Sin[1/2]^2 - 
      768 E^t Cos[1/2] Sin[t] + 396 E^(1/2 + t) Cos[1/2]^2 Sin[t] + 
      396 E^(1/2 + t) Sin[1/2]^2 Sin[t])];
```

In Figure 10 shown numerical solution (left) and exact solution (right, blue line) with numerical solution (red points):
[image: Figure 10]
Finally we have to compare absolute error $|B(t)-u(0,t)|$ for code by Chris K and my code to find out accuracy of two code. For Chris code it is obvious that error is of `h` and for my code theoretically it should be of $h^3$. But since we solve PDE it is not so perfect. In Figure 11 shown absolute error for Chris code (left) and for my code (right) for imax=np=800. It looks like my code has error of $h^{3/2}$ not $h^3$.
[image: Figure 11]
To improve the accuracy of my code we add point `a=0` to the grid for differentiation matrix and finally have

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

np = 40; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 1];
ugrid = g[[All, 1]]; weights = g[[All, 2]]; grid = Join[{0}, ugrid];


fd = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], grid]; m = 
 fd["DifferentiationMatrix"]; vart = 
 Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[grid]}]; varti = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, 2, Length[grid]}]; vart1 = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, Length[grid]}]; ux = m.vart; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, Length[grid]}];

\[Mu][a_] := 1/(1 - a); 
p0[x_] := If[x <= 1/2, (1 - 2 x)^3 (1 - x), 31 (2 x - 1)^3 (1 - x)];
u0[a_] := p0[a];

f[a_] := 2; int = Table[f[ugrid[[i]]] weights[[i]], {i, np}]; eqns = 
 Join[{D[u[1][t], t] == int.varti}, 
  Flatten[Table[
    u[i]'[t] == -ux[[i]] - \[Mu][grid[[i]]] u[i][t], {i, 2, 
     Length[grid]}]]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[grid[[i]]], {i, Length[grid]}];
tmax = 1;
{bb, mm} = CoefficientArrays[eqns, vart1];
rhs = -Inverse[mm].bb;
sol1 = NDSolve[{Table[vart1[[i]] == rhs[[i]], {i, Length[vart1]}], 
    ics}, var, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

With this code we calculate absolute error in Example 1 for `np=40`(left picture) and `np=80` (right picture). For this code error is of $h^{5/2}$.
[image: Figure 12]

Comment: I'm not sure you can take the analytical solution derived without the integral boundary condition, and use it to determine the boundary condition in `NDSolve`.  You can calculate the basic reproduction number $R_0$ (expected number of offspring produced over a lifetime) for this model as `NIntegrate[E^(-1/80*a) f[a], {a, 0, 100}]` which is 1.672, so the population should grow, not go extinct.

Comment: @ChrisK I used general solution of PDE with initial data $u(a,0)=u_0(a)$. This kind of solution exist and `DSolve[]` found it. The boundary condition $u(0,t)$ been used for numerical solution restricted on `a`.

Comment: @ChrisK See update to my answer with comparison of your and my solutions.

Comment: This isn't OP's original problem though.  You decreased the birth rate `f[a]` from 0.1 to 0.025, so it's not surprising that the population dies off.  The boundary condition represents reproduction, so it's an essential part of this model that can't just be changed to avoid `NDSolve` warnings.

Comment: @ChrisK But this is unique solution with boundary and initial conditions are consistent. Also there are some not unique solutions with inconsistent boundary and initial conditions and you shown some of them.

Comment: @ChrisK See update with example of growing population. Please check, that  two solutions fond with your method and my method agreed up to small numerical error.

Comment: Hi Alex, they seem to match in this case, but I'm still dubious whether this approach works in general.  Here you used a particular initial condition, that at least has the same exponential shape as the stable age distribution, and still different birth rate than OP's question.  I just don't think you can pre-compute the births (integral boundary condition) then plug it into the rest.  They need to be coupled.  Check out chapter 7 of [Brauer and Castilllo-Chavez](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-1686-9_7) if you can get it.  The inconsistent BC/IC doesn't matter for $t>0$.

Comment: @ChrisK Ok, I have got two examples to support your model (my model more clear and don't need verification). If you are not agree with this then I am sorry. :)  Also we don't need to read chapter 7 to understand difference between case when boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent and case when its consistent.

Comment: @Chirs We can't extract b.c. at $a=0$ from the symbolic solution, because the symbolic solution is obtained assuming the solution is defined in $-\infty<a<+\infty$. Since $a\geq 0$, the symbolic solution makes sense only if $a\geq t$. (To Alex: see comments under the question for more info. )

Comment: @xzczd Nevertheless, numerical solutions found out with two method are in agreement  for $0 \le a \le 100$ in the first and second example, and for $20\le a\le 20+t$ in the last example. Also first method been used to verifier the second one.  Finally I have proposed numerical algorithm of 4th order.  Now I am looking for a bench mark test.

Answer (score 4):

To give some convincing publication to the round of answerers and the owner of the question: [Numerical methods for the Lotka–McKendrick’s equation
Galena Pelovska, Mimmo Iannelli∗
Dipartimento di Matematica, Universita degli Studi di Trento, via Sommarive 14, I-38050 Povo(Trento), Italy](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82725634.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting