# Discretization of the following integral: an optimal way

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, discretization

Consider an integral

$$
I[f_{n},T]=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} dE_{n}F(f_{n}(E_{n}),E_{n},T)+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} dE_{n}\int_{\mathcal{F}(E_{n})}dE_{n}^{'}G(f_{n}(E_{n}),f_{n}(E_{n}^{'}),E_{n},E_{n}^{'},T),
$$
where $T>0$ is some parameter, while $f_{n}$ is the distribution function. The integral has the property that for $f_{n} = e^{-E_{n}/T_{n}}$, it 1) is negative if $T_{n}>T$, 2) vanishes at $T_{n} = T$, 3) positive if $T<T_{n}$.

The integral $I$ enters some partial integrodifferential equation on $f_{n}(E_{n},t)$ which I want to solve as a set of ODEs with the help of the discretization of $E$ domain (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233726/solving-the-following-system-of-integrodifferential-equations-speed-up-of-the-c)). Therefore, I need to discretize this integral.

The integral in continuous and discrete forms, $f_{n} = e^{-E_{n}/T_{n}}$, is given below (the final functions are `CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannContinuous[T, Tn], CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannDiscretized[T, Tn]`). To discretize it, I have just used $E_{n} \to E_{\text{min}}+i\Delta E$, where $0\leqslant i \leqslant imax$, and $\int dE_{n} \to \Delta E \sum_{i}$.

```
(*Some parameters*)
hbar = 6.582119*10^-25;
sToGeVminusOne = 1/hbar;
sToMeVminusOne = sToGeVminusOne*10^-3;
(*Discretization of En values*)
imax = 100;
DEvalue = 0.25;
Emin = 0.01;
Estep[k_] = Emin + DEvalue*k;
fnBoltzmannDiscrete[k_, Tn_] = Exp[-Estep[k]/Tn];
fnThermalBoltzmann[E\[Nu]_, Tn_] = Exp[-E\[Nu]/Tn];


(*Integral I-continuous*)
dS11dE2[E1_, E2_] = -0.0034976546222801287` E1 E2^3*fn[E1] fn[E2];
S12[E1_, T_] = 0.02098592773368077` Exp[-E1/T] E1 T^4;
S21[E1_, T_] = -0.08394371093472308` E1 T^4 fn[E1];
dS221dE2[E1_, E2_, T_] = 
  0.03147889160052116`/(E1^2) Exp[-E1/
     T] T^2 (-E1^2 (E2^2 + 2 E2 T - 2 (-1 + Exp[E2/T]) T^2) - 
     2 E1 T (E2^2 + 2 E2 T - 2 (-1 + Exp[E2/T]) T^2) + 
     2 T^2 ((-1 + Exp[E2/T]) E2^2 - 2 (1 + Exp[E2/T]) E2 T + 
        4 (-1 + Exp[E2/T]) T^2)) fn[E2];
dS222dE2[E1_, E2_, T_] = 
  0.03147889160052116`/(E1^2) Exp[-E1/
     T] T^2 (2 (-1 + Exp[E1/T]) T^2 (E2^2 + 2 E2 T + 4 T^2) - 
     E1^2 (E2^2 + 2 E2 T - 2 (-1 + Exp[E1/T]) T^2) - 
     2 E1 T (E2^2 + 2 E2 T + 2 (1 + Exp[E1/T]) T^2)) fn[E2];
CollisionIntegralContinuous[E1_, T_] := 
 S12[E1, T] + S21[E1, T] + 
  NIntegrate[dS11dE2[E1, E2], {E2, 0, Infinity}] + 
  NIntegrate[dS221dE2[E1, E2, T], {E2, 0, E1}] + 
  NIntegrate[dS222dE2[E1, E2, T], {E2, E1, Infinity}]
CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannContinuous[T_, Tn_] := 
 NIntegrate[((S12[E1, T] + S21[E1, T]) /. {fn[E1] -> 
        fnThermalBoltzmann[E1, Tn]}) E1^3/(2*Pi^2), {E1, 0, 
    Infinity}] + 
  NIntegrate[(dS11dE2[E1, 
       E2] /. {fn[E1] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E1, Tn], 
       fn[E2] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E2, Tn]}) E1^3/(2*Pi^2), {E1, 0, 
    Infinity}, {E2, 0, Infinity}] + 
  NIntegrate[(dS221dE2[E1, E2, 
       T] /. {fn[E1] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E1, Tn], 
       fn[E2] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E2, Tn]}) E1^3/(2*Pi^2), {E1, 0, 
    Infinity}, {E2, 0, E1}] + 
  NIntegrate[(dS222dE2[E1, E2, 
       T] /. {fn[E1] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E1, Tn], 
       fn[E2] -> fnThermalBoltzmann[E2, Tn]}) E1^3/(2*Pi^2), {E1, 0, 
    Infinity}, {E2, E1, Infinity}]

(*Integral I-discretized*)
dS11dE2discrete[i_, j_] = 
  dS11dE2[E1, E2] /. {fn[E1] -> fn[i][t], 
     fn[E2] -> fn[j][t]} /. {E1 -> Estep[i], E2 -> Estep[j]};
S12discrete[i_] = 
  S12[E1, T] /. {fn[E1] -> fn[i][t], fn[E2] -> fn[j][t]} /. {E1 -> 
     Estep[i], E2 -> Estep[j]};
S21discrete[i_] = 
  S21[E1, T] /. {fn[E1] -> fn[i][t], fn[E2] -> fn[j][t]} /. {E1 -> 
     Estep[i], E2 -> Estep[j]};
dS221dE2discrete[i_, j_] = 
  dS221dE2[E1, E2, T] /. {fn[E1] -> fn[i][t], 
     fn[E2] -> fn[j][t]} /. {E1 -> Estep[i], E2 -> Estep[j]};
dS222dE2discrete[i_, j_] = 
  dS222dE2[E1, E2, T] /. {fn[E1] -> fn[i][t], 
     fn[E2] -> fn[j][t]} /. {E1 -> Estep[i], E2 -> Estep[j]};
CollisionIntegralDiscrete[
  i_] := (S12discrete[i] + S21discrete[i] + 
    DEvalue*Sum[dS11dE2discrete[i, j], {j, 0, imax, 1}] + 
    DEvalue*Sum[dS221dE2discrete[i, j], {j, 0, i, 1}] + 
    If[i == imax, 0, 
     DEvalue*Sum[
       dS222dE2discrete[i, j], {j, i + 1, imax, 1}]]) /. {T -> Tg[t]}
CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannDiscrete[Tg_, 
  Tn_] := (DEvalue*
     Sum[((S12discrete[i] + S21discrete[i]) /. {fn[i][t] -> 
           fnBoltzmannDiscrete[i, Tn]}) (Estep[i])^3/(2*Pi^2), {i, 0, 
       imax, 1}] + 
    DEvalue^2*
     Sum[(dS11dE2discrete[i, 
          j] /. {fn[i][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[i, Tn], 
          fn[j][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[j, Tn]}) (Estep[i])^3/(
       2*Pi^2), {i, 0, imax, 1}, {j, 0, imax, 1}] + 
    DEvalue^2*
     Sum[(dS221dE2discrete[i, 
          j] /. {fn[i][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[i, Tn], 
          fn[j][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[j, Tn]}) (Estep[i])^3/(
       2*Pi^2), {i, 0, imax, 1}, {j, 0, i, 1}] + 
    DEvalue^2*
     Sum[If[i == imax, 0, 
       Sum[(dS222dE2discrete[i, 
            j] /. {fn[i][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[i, Tn], 
            fn[j][t] -> fnBoltzmannDiscrete[j, Tn]}) (Estep[i])^3/(
         2*Pi^2), {j, i + 1, imax, 1}]], {i, 0, imax, 1}]) /. {T -> Tg}
```

Comparing the values of `CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannContinuous[T, Tn], CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannDiscretized[T, Tn]` at $T = T_{n} = 2$, $T = T_{n} = 3$ for `DEvalue = 0.25` and `imax = 100`, I find

```
Timing[CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannDiscrete[3, 3]]
CollisionIntegralIntegratedBoltzmannContinuous[3, 3]
```

> {0.941387,-43.7787}

> -9.28833*10^-6

This is a very poor agreement. It may be improved by increasing `imax` and decreasing `DEvalue`. Namely, for `DEvalue = 0.05` and `imax = 1000`, I get

> {98.1421, -0.182558}

The agreement is somewhat better now. However, this improvement is accompanied by a significant increase in timing. This problem suggests that the way of the discretization that is used in my code is poor.

Could you please tell me how to discretize more efficiently, assuming that it may be used for "arbitrary" $f_{n}$ (in the sense that this integral $I$ is evaluated for dynamically changed $f_{n}$)?