# NDsolve Boundary Condition is a Function of the Solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, integral-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve something like Fick's Law using `NDSolve`:
$$\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial r^2}+F(r,t)$$
Subject to a boundary condition which looks something like:
$$\varphi (R,t)=\varphi_0-\int_0^R \varphi(r,t)dr$$
Which is an attempt to simulate the case where whatever is diffusing into the medium of interest is limited in quantity. I assume simply plugging a recursive boundary condition is going to go poorly (Edit: it did go poorly), is there any option here other than writing my own solver?

In specific one particular case could look like:
$$\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r}(2r+r^3/3-\int\varphi r^2dr)-\varphi$$
In this case $\varphi_0=1$ and the initial condition is $\varphi(0\leq r<R,0)=0$, where $R=1$. The problem should have spherical symmetry so a bound at $r=0$ may result in trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: The method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78564/1063) may be helpful.

Comment: Readers are more likely to respond, if you provide all the necessary information to obtain a numerical solution, including the definitions of `F`, the values of `R` and  `phi0`, and the initial condition and other boundary condition.

Comment: As it turns out the method of lines was a nudge in the right direction, I found a few more posts on the topic of integro-differential equations and their boundary conditions at it looks like there are a few other avenues to try (possibly replacing $\varphi$ with its x-partial-derivative to eliminate the integral terms?).

Comment: @UranylTrioxide  What was the  outcome of your effort?

Comment: Ultimately the problem turned out to be poorly formulated on my part, some more careful work revealed that the system that I wanted to solve wasn't this one at all